# Error initiating treemac

Tags: version-compatibilty, treemacs

initiating treemac is giving this error. I just don't understand all the errors that emacs throws up. 
I just have 
`(require 'treemacs)` in init file.

version-to-list: Invalid version syntax: ‘'"'where' is not recognized as an internal or external command,"' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.’ (must start with a number)

Comment: You should open an issue at https://github.com/Alexander-Miller/treemacs

Comment: @ComproPrasad Did you already [fix that problem](https://github.com/Compro-Prasad/treemacs/commit/53e8bccf334098f3a9e573a3e8dc8e84aab80c50)? If so did you send a pull-request to the original repository of Alexander Miller?

Comment: IMHO this question is a bit incomplete as it doesn't include any backtrace, Emacs version, Python version and other stuff. It doesn't emphasize what is the error here. If it were a GitHub issue, it would be easier to discuss it with the maintainer too. I didn't fix it. Its already in the repository. It was fixed by Nik Clayton. https://github.com/Alexander-Miller/treemacs/commit/53e8bccf334098f3a9e573a3e8dc8e84aab80c50

Comment: how do i understand if it is a Github issue